# Java Switch Case Boolean functions?

Tags: java, switch-statement, boolean, case

I'm doing some Java homework and I am on a problem that has a code relating to converting test scores to letter grades where errors must be found:

```
switch(score)
{
case (score > 90):
grade = 'A';
break;
etc...
```

Everywhere I've read, and everything I've tried in netbeans says boolean functions aren't allowed. Is the error that it should just be an if statement?

Comment: I do not fully understand your last two sentences but what you are trying to do will not work with `switch ... case ...`, use `if`s instead.

Comment: Seems like what you read is correct. Is that the confirmation you're looking for? And yes, a chain of `if/else if` seems more appropriate.

Comment: I think you don't understand the last two sentences because it's part of the error. That was the confirmation I was looking for, that a boolean function wouldn't work in a switch case. Thank you guys for your help and reassurance I wasn't crazy.

Answer (score 0):

The content associated to the `case` has to compatible with the type of the expression used in the `switch`.
You use an `int` (probably) in the `switch`, so the `case`s have to be `int` values (or another type convertible to an `int` such as a `char` for example). The problem is that you provide a `boolean` that is not convertible to an `int` and whatever it is not what you are looking for.

The [JLS.14.11. The switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) states indeed :

> Given a switch statement, all of the following must be true or a
>   compile-time error occurs:
>
> Every case constant associated with the switch statement must be
>   assignment compatible with the type of the switch statement's
>   Expression (§5.2).

If the two types don't match, you don't want to use a `switch` but a series of conditional statements (`if-else-if`) instead of.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JLS, the parameters of the case statements can only be `int`, `short`, `byte`, `char`, `String` or `Enum` literals or constants.

So to answer your question, the given code will not compile and yes, it should be an `if` statement.